# Prove the Classification of Open Sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We were told to prove that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals using equivalence classes in the following way:

1. Consider the following relation on a given open set $\mathcal{O}$: $x \sim y$ iff $[x,y] \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ or  $[y,x] \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ depending on whether $x \leq y$ or $y \leq x$. Show that it is an equivalence relation. 
   **DONE**
2. Denote the equivalence class of $x \in \mathcal{O}$ by $I_{x}$.  Consider the extended reals $a_{x} = \inf I_{x}$, $b_{x} = \sup I_{x}$.  Show that $a_{x}, b_{x} \notin I_{x}$. (Hint: Use $\mathcal{O}$ being open.) Conclude $I_{x} = (a_{x}, b_{x})$; i.e., that $I_{x}$ is an open interval. **I think this is done, but is it ok to just conclude that Ix is open since the supremum and infinum aren't elements in the set.**
3. Conclude that $\mathcal{O}$ is a disjoint union of open intervals Ix. **I have no idea how to show this!**
4. Show that the union must be countable. **I want to show that each Ix contains a single rational point.  This is intuitively obvious, but not sure how to prove it**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that $a_x \notin I_x$, because then $a_x$ would have to be an interior point of $\mathcal O$, and therefore the (WLOG) symmetric interval around $a_x$ given by it's openness would also have to be in $I_x$ by definition of $I_x$, contradicting the fact that no point to the left of $a_x$ belongs in $I_x$. Similarly, $b_x \notin I_x$.

From here, the fact that $I_x$ does not contain it's supremum and infimum, is enough to show that $I_x$ is open, *provided you show that $I_x$ is an interval for all $x$*. If you can show this, and it is quite easy, then you are correct and done for this part.

Indeed, for the third part, we have a more general statement, which  I urge your to prove, in fact you must have seen it already:

> If $S$ is a set, and $R$ is an equivalence relation on $S$, then $S$ is partitioned into the equivalence classes given by $R$.

So, applying this simple lemma, we see that if $S = \mathcal O$ and $\sim$ is the relation $x\sim y$ given in the question, then this essentially says that $S = \bigcup I_x$, where $I_x$ are the equivalence classes of $S$,and the union is disjoint, since $I_x$ is a partition of $S$. That finishes part 3.

As for the fourth part, let $I$ be an index set for the union $S = \bigcup_{i \in I} I_i$. What I mean by this statement, is that I don't know how many equivalence classes there are : there could be just one, there could be say 254, there could be countably infinite of these, there could even be uncountably many of those. Since we don't know the number ,we just use some "abstract" index set to refer to these sets $I_i$. So for example, if there was only one equivalence class, then $I = \{1\}$ and there will be only one equivalence class, $I_i$. If there are 254 equivalence classes, then I could take $I = \{1,2,...,254\}$ and the equivalence classes would be $I_1,I_2,...,I_{254}$, for example.

Now, at this stage, saying that there are countably many equivalence classes, is the same as saying that $I$ is countable, since  $I$ counts the number of equivalence classes. Consider a map from $I \to \mathbb Q$, given by $f(i) = r$, where $r$ is any rational number in $I_i$. This is a well defined map. If you can show that this map is injective, then it will follow that $I$ is atmost countable. I leave you to see, from the disjointness of $I_i$ from $I_j$ for $i \neq j \in I$, why this map is injective.

Finally, $S = \bigcup_{i \in I} I_i$, and $I$ is countable, hence the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

To show that the equivalence class $[x]_{\sim}=\{y:y\sim x\},$ for $x\in O,$ is open :  For $y\in [x]_{\sim}$ we have $[y]_{\sim}=[x]_{\sim}$ and  there exists $r>0$ such that $(-r+y,r+y)\subset O.$ From the def'n of $\sim$ we have   $y\in (-r+y,r+y)\subset [y]_{\sim}=[x]_{\sim}\;.$

There are many ways to show that $\mathbb Q$ is countable. So let $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb Q$ be a bijection. For $x\in O$ let $g([x]_{\sim})$ be the least $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $f(n)\in [x]_{\sim}\;.$ ( Note that $\mathbb Q\cap [x]_{\sim}\ne \emptyset$ because $[x]_{\sim}$ is a non-empty open set.)

The $\sim-$equivalence classes are pair-wise disjoint so $ g $ is injective.